# Reply and append text to body of e-mail using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email

I have the following VBA code that is run from Excel:

```
Sub olReply()

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

For Each objMsg In objSelection

    Set oReply = objMsg.Reply
    oReply.Body = "test" & objMsg.Body
    oReply.Display

Next

Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Set oReply = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm trying to get this code to reply to a selected e-mail in outlook and append my own text ("test" above) to the top of the original text of the e-mail.

I've searched for a solution and it should be quite straightforward but running this code produces a "Run-time error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error".

The error is produced at the following section:

```
oReply.Body = "test" & objMsg.Body
```

...and specifically at objMsg.Body as I step through the code using F8. If I change this from objMsg.Body to objMsg.Subject for example, the code runs fine, replying to the e-mail adding my own text and the subject line of the original e-mail.

Not sure what I'm missing as I'm not a VBA pro and this is my first post, so hoping you guys can point me in the right direction or suggest an alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest running the following VBA macro in Outlook:

```
Sub olReply()
 Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
 Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
 Set objOL = Application
 Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
 For Each objMsg In objSelection
  Set oReply = objMsg.Reply
  oReply.Body = "test" & objMsg.Body
  oReply.Display
 Next
 Set objMsg = Nothing
 Set objSelection = Nothing
 Set objOL = Nothing
 Set oReply = Nothing
End Sub
```

Do you get any errors in that case?

If not, you get a standard "object model guard" security issue. See [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) for more information.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I've just been able to try your suggestion. You're right, the code works fine as a VBA macro in Outlook. Do you know what the workaround is taking into account the "Object Model Guard" security issue?

Comment: See [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) for possible options.